# Getting Build URi or Build number of the last build from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-buildengine

I am trying to create a custom task for MSBuild so that it will send an email to the users that sais that a new version is up on the test server.

I go the email part done, what i would like to do is add the work items that are included in this build. 
I tried the MSBuild extention (used to send the email) but the feature to get that info is not supporte don TFS 2005 wich is what i am using and cannot upgrade.

I was trying to use BuildStore.GetWorkItemsForBuild but i need a builduri which i cannot find a way to get.

The setup is like this, the steps to compile, build and deploy are called from a batch file as diffrent options. At the end of the deploy option, the email is sent.

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible but it seems your'e trying to stretch MSBuild functionality for tasks that related to build management.
Consider a solution like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) that wraps for you all the build processes and manage notifications (i.e. when build has succeed or failed). It has out-of-the-box support for MSBuild.